# Sum function in SQL search

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find out how many accounts in a system have a 1 in a particular field. The code I am using is as follows:

```
Select  Member_Id,    
        LoanAccount_ID,
        SUM(Dormant) as SDormant
From    LoanAccountBal
Group by member_ID, LoanAccount_ID, SDormant
Order by Member_ID asc, LoanAccount_ID asc
```

However, when I try to run this code, I get the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Invalid column name 'SDormant'.

How do I get the code to recognise the new column name and sum function?

Edit: to explain better.

For both Member_ID and LoanAccount_ID there are multiple entries with the same parameters (e.g. there could be 200 of Member_ID: 1, LoanAccount_ID: 200). Only 1 of these may have a code of Dormant (value of 1), while the rest could be empty. I need to aggregate the the Member_IDs and LoanAccount_IDs, and also count how many entries have a value in the Dormant field. Hope this is a better explanation.

Comment: Why do you need to group your aggregate?  It doesn't make sense.  Remove `SDormant` from the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error you're getting is because you can't `GROUP BY` a column alias because the SQL engine evaluates the `GROUP BY` clause before it evaluates the `SELECT` clause in the query. At the point that it's doing the grouping, `SDormant` doesn't exist yet.

You also can't `GROUP BY` an aggregate expression, because that makes one's head explode.

Based on your edit, this might get you what you want. It should show each `Member_ID`/`LoanAccount_ID` pair, the total `Dormant` loans, the total *not* `Dormant` loans, and the sum of the two, just as a sanity check.

```
    Select  Member_Id,    
            LoanAccount_ID,
            SUM(Dormant) AS SDormant,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Dormant = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotDormant,
            COUNT(*) AS TotalCount
    From    LoanAccountBal
    Group by member_ID, LoanAccount_ID
    Order by Member_ID asc, LoanAccount_ID asc
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your query has to do with your question.  But you normally would not be using `SUM()` on a column in the `GROUP BY`.  So I think this is the query you want to write:

```
Select Member_Id, LoanAccount_ID, SUM(Dormant) as SDormant
From LoanAccountBal
Group by member_ID, LoanAccount_ID
Order by Member_ID asc, LoanAccount_ID asc;
```

For your question, though, I would expect a condition in your query, perhaps:

```
where <some column> = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description i would do :

```
Select Member_Id, LoanAccount_ID, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN <particular field> = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SDormant
From LoanAccountBal
Group by member_ID, LoanAccount_ID
Order by Member_ID asc, LoanAccount_ID asc;
```

Other option would be to use `COUNT()` with `WHERE` clause :

```
Select Member_Id, LoanAccount_ID, COUNT(*) as SDormant
From LoanAccountBal
WHERE <particular field> = 1
Group by member_ID, LoanAccount_ID
Order by Member_ID asc, LoanAccount_ID asc;
```

EDIT : Assuming the empty word means `null` if so, then you just need `count()`

```
Select Member_Id, LoanAccount_ID, COUNT(Dormant) as SDormant
From LoanAccountBal
Group by member_ID, LoanAccount_ID
Order by Member_ID asc, LoanAccount_ID asc;
```

However the second version query would also work, if you just modify the `WHERE` clause as :

```
WHERE Dormant IS NOT NULL
```